# Can't scrape information from a static webpage using requests module

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to fetch `product title` and it's `description` from a [webpage](https://www.nordstrom.com/s/anine-bing-womens-plaid-shirt/6638030) using requests module. The title and description appear to be static as they both are present in page source. However, I failed to grab them using following attempt. The script throws `AttributeError` at this moment.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = 'https://www.nordstrom.com/s/anine-bing-womens-plaid-shirt/6638030'

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers.update(headers)
    res = s.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
    product_title = soup.select_one("h1[itemProp='name']").text
    product_desc = soup.select_one("#product-page-selling-statement").text
    print(product_title,product_desc)
```

> How can I scrape title and description from above pages using requests module?

Comment: They are not in the static html. Where are you seeing that?

Comment: After pressing (Ctrl + U) when you look for this id `product-page-selling-statement` in page source, you should get the description and then `[itemProp='name']` to get the title.

Comment: That's not actually what's returned in your request. print out `print(res.text)`, and you'll see it's not in there.

Comment: You can get similar content in response only when you use cookies while issuing requests.

Answer (score 2):

The page is dynamic. go after the data from the api source:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

api = 'https://www.nordstrom.com/api/ng-looks/styleId/6638030?customerId=f36cf526cfe94a72bfb710e5e155f9ba&limit=7'
jsonData = requests.get(api).json()

df = pd.json_normalize(jsonData['products'].values())

print(df.iloc[0])
```

**Output:**

```
id                                                       6638030-400
name                                  ANINE BING Women's Plaid Shirt
styleId                                                      6638030
styleNumber                                                         
colorCode                                                        400
colorName                                                       BLUE
brandLabelName                                            ANINE BING
hasFlatShot                                                     True
imageUrl           https://n.nordstrommedia.com/id/sr3/6d000f40-8...
price                                                        $149.00
pathAlias          anine-bing-womens-plaid-shirt/6638030?origin=c...
originalPrice                                                $149.00
productTypeLvl1                                                   12
productTypeLvl2                                                  216
isUmap                                                         False
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

Comment: It's a nice approach to get things partially done. However, it fails miserably when url like `https://www.nordstrom.com/s/mens-champion-purple-lsu-tigers-classic-shorts/6870106` comes into play.

Comment: Cuz you’re not using the api there.

Comment: This is `https://www.nordstrom.com/api/ng-looks/styleId/6870106?customerId=f36cf526cfe94a72bfb710e5e155f9ba&limit=7` what I meant to be specific.

Comment: I see. That api gets the styles that item could go with. In terms of the LSU men's shorts, there are not other products to create a "style" with, so it doesn't return anything. The other option is to go after that with the other api which gets other recommendations of the product, but that looks tricky in that you need to have additional parameters such as style ids, etc. Yes you are correct if you feed in the cookie, you can get from the basic url, but the request session doesn't get all the cookies needed (likely generated by javascript), and as mentioned it seems they have a mechanism...

Comment: ...to block an ip after multiple requests. So you could try Selenium here to render that page and then parse the html.

Answer (score 0):

When testing requests like these you should output the response to see what you're getting back. Best to use something like Postman (I think VSCode has a similar function to it now) to set up URLs, headers, methods, and parameters, and to also see the full response with headers. When you have everything working right, just convert it to python code. Postman even has some 'export to code' functions for common languages.

Anyways...

I tried your request on Postman and got this response:
[image: simple response body]

[image: simple response headers]

Requests done from python vs a browser are the same thing. If the headers, URLs, and parameters are identical, they should receive identical responses. So the next step is comparing the difference between your request and the request done by the browser:
[image: browser request]

So one or more of the headers included by the browser gets a good response from the server, but just using `User-Agent` is not enough.

I would try to identify which headers, but unfortunately, Nordstrom detected some 'unusual activity' and seems to have blocked my IP :(
[image: blocked]
Probably due to sending an obvious handmade request. I think it's my IP that's blocked since I can't access the site from any browser, even after clearing my cache.

So double-check that the same hasn't happened to you while working with your scraper.

Best of luck!